# What is the right jQuery (or javaScript) code to pause a basic slider using a simple 'setTimeOut' funcitonality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, carousel

I have built a basic content slider, based upon a tutorial I got from the web.

In the example, the slides scroll on a timed interval using a `setTimeout` parameter, but also has a navigation functionality (of course) which allows you to go to selected slides directly.

The slides scroll without pausing the `Timeout` when a slide is selected and obviously when the mouse hovers.

The ***key*** javaScript/jQuery code which controls the scrolling is essentially (7 total slides):

```
var currentSlide = 0;

function slideScroll(){
    if (currentSlide == 7)
    selectSlide(1);
else
    selectSlide( currentSlide + 1 );

setTimeout ('slideScroll()', 4000);

}
```

((*Other javaScript code omitted because I was fairly certain that the key is this function, but I can certainly update my question with the precursory code if needed for clarity.*))

The end game is **a)** to have the `Timeout` reset whenever a user selects a new slide and **b)** to have the `Timeout` pause when a mouse is rolled over the content in the slide.

I presume that the code ought to be inserted in conjunction with the `setTimeout`, with some `if` statements or something. Can someone help me devise this solution for endgame **a)** and **b)** ?

Live prototype and ***NOT*** a shameless plug: [HERE](http://www.bcw.se/3point0/)

Thanks in advance for tips!

Comment: This is called a "carousel". [Slider means something different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slider_\(computing\))

Comment: a live http://jsfiddle.net would be great to see the code and demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a check for paused and a variable to hold the timer reference

```
var currentSlide = 0,
    paused = 0,
    timer;

function slideScroll () {
    if (paused) {/* action if paused or leave blank*/}
    else if (currentSlide === 7) selectSlide(1);
    else selectSlide(currentSlide + 1);
    timer = setTimeout(slideScroll, 4000);
}
```

Then in the choose slide click

```
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(slideScroll, 4000);
```

Then in mouseover

```
paused = 1;
```

and mouseout

```
pause = 0;
```

---

Alternatively, use a shorter timeout which does almost nothing most times it's invoked

```
var currentSlide = 0,
    paused = 0,
    remain = 4000;

function slideScroll () {
    if (!paused) {
        if (remain > 0) remain -= 200;
        else {
            remain = 4000;
            if (currentSlide === 7) selectSlide(1);
            else selectSlide(currentSlide + 1);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(slideScroll, 200);
}
```

Then in the choose slide click

```
remain = 4000;
```

Same as before for mouseover and mouseout